# jQuery How to get textarea maxlenght as integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get `maxlength` of `textarea` as integer and make operation on it. 
I used `ParseInt` and when I check `typeof` the value it is a number. 
but when I try to print the number in console or try to add this number with another number the result is `NaN` !

```
     <textarea cols="30" rows="15" maxlength="50"></textarea>
      <span></span>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    var textAreaLength = parseInt($('textarea').attr('maxlenght'));
    console.log(typeof textAreaLength); // result is number
    console.log(textAreaLength); // result is NaN !
    $('textarea').keyup(function(){
        var writtenCharacters = parseInt($('textarea').val().length);
        var remainingCharacters = textAreaLength - writtenCharacters;
        $('.textareaSpan').html("You have written :" + writtenCharacters + " characters <br> Your remaining chracters:" + remainingCharacters);
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var textAreaLength = parseInt($('textarea').attr('maxlenght'));
```

with

```
var textAreaLength = parseInt($('textarea').attr('maxlength'));
```

spelling of `maxlength` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks :s . I didn't noticed the spelling